# Picking random points on a hexagon

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image: problem statement]

I tried to solve this the following way: I know that the bottom is 12C3 or 220. Regarding the top, I have 6 favorable outcomes (because there are 6 line segments on which the chosen 3 points can lie on) so my answer is 6/220 or 3/110 which is not even one of the choices! the answer key says: 3/220. Can someone elaborate why 3 instead of 6?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are right, the answer key is wrong.

Comment: but my answer is not even one of the answer choices!

Comment: I got the same answer as you.